# How wide is a null column in a table in a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, null, diskspace

Do `null` columns consume the same space on disk as when transferred over the network to a client?

How wide, in bytes, is a `null` column in a table in a PostgreSQL database?

Comment: [A search reveals more related questions and aswers.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+null+space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missed your second question at first:

Most clients communicate with the db server via text. Depending on the format that's either the string `NULL` or *nothing* (for instance in `COPY` output or the text format of pg_dump) instead of a value.
This is *completely different* from how `NULL` values are stored inside the database. (See added links.)

Comment: Do you happen to know if the PostgreSQL JDBC driver in particular communicates with the server in plain text?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/protocol-message-formats.html describes the messages in the PostgreSQL wire protocol.  Message `DataRow` explains that a `Null` column is assigned size -1 and has zero data bytes.

Comment: @DerekMahar Yes, PgJDBC uses the text protocol. It has some support for the binary protocol but I don't recommend using it for anything except transferring lots of `bytea` values.